# How to skip a header line in a csv file using scanner?

Tags: java

This is my code so far:

```
public List<Entry> getEntries() throws FileNotFoundException {

        List<Entry> result = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("src/fp/sales/sales-data.csv"));

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            List<String> attributes = List.of(line.split("\t"));
            LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(attributes.get(0), formatter);

            Entry entry = new Entry(date, attributes.get(1), attributes.get(2), attributes.get(3), Double.valueOf(attributes.get(5)));
            result.add(entry);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I would like to skip the header line, because it won't work with it. How can I do this?

Comment: Read it and discard it with `scanner.nextLine()` before the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Answer by [@Jhonny Mopp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/669576/johnny-mopp)

```
public List<Entry> getEntries() throws FileNotFoundException {

        List<Entry> result = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("src/fp/sales/sales-data.csv"));
    String line = scanner.nextLine(); // ignore the first line of your file 
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            List<String> attributes = List.of(line.split("\t"));
            LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(attributes.get(0), formatter);

            Entry entry = new Entry(date, attributes.get(1), attributes.get(2), attributes.get(3), Double.valueOf(attributes.get(5)));
            result.add(entry);
        }
        return null;
    }
```